# Update PHP Sessions with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

Basically I want to resize my page and objects according to screen resolution. I can't use Media Queries because I need to resize some flash and JS objects as well by passing the width, not only HTML elements.

So, I was thinking to store the screen width in a PHP SESSION variable using AJAX request. To do so, I have below code. But the issue is, the session variable gets updated after next page refresh. I am sure I am missing pretty much straight forward thing, but just can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Main.php:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
<script>
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type:'POST',
    url: 'screen.php',
    data: 'width=1400'
    }).complete(function(data){
        alert(<?php echo "SESSION value in main.php: ".$_SESSION['test_width'];?>);
        alert(data.responseText);
    });
</script>
```

screen.php

```
if(isset($_POST['width'])){
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['test_width'] = $_POST['width'];
    echo "SESSION value in screen.php: ".$_SESSION['test_width'];
}
```

outputs:

```
SESSION value in main.php: 1300 //LAST VALUE
SESSION value in screen.php: 1400 // CURRENT VALUE
```

Comment: When you say "the session variable gets updated after next page refresh", do you mean "I get a new session ID on every page load"?

Comment: No, session_id() remains same. It's just that change of value of $_SESSION['test_width'] takes affect after I refresh the page. For example, with above code, if I refresh the page, only after that i will have output "SESSION value in main.php: 1400"

Comment: That is correct, that's how sessions work. Instead of having PHP code on the page echo $_SESSION['test_width'], maybe try passing a JSON result back from the AJAX call to screen.php, and parse that in your .complete() function, and update the page using jQuery instead of static PHP.

Comment: hmm .. i was thinking that might be the case. Thanks for confirming. So, I can't actually follow this approach?

Comment: you cannot access the future value of a session key prior to setting it, no

Comment: I was thinking by the time $.ajax.complete gets called, the new value of session key was already set, so should get the new value inside .complete function. I guess I have to read a bit about sessions again.

Comment: css CAN change size of flash objects, what is even js objects?...regardless...medida queries can be used to serve css that is needed.

Comment: Why not use the [local browser storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to have the screen size. It'll persist and can be easily accessed in javascript. Jquery has a pretty well documented [API](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/) leveraging this. You might want to give it a try and completely do away with `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: PHP executes all of the page code, at once, rendering it to static HTML. On the first time you visit the page, $_SESSION has no values in it, but $_SESSION['test_width'] RIGHT NOW. After ALL OF THIS PHP has been rendered into HTML, it is sent to the user's browser, where the javascript code (your `complete` function) will then be called - but the missing PHP session value was already turned into HTML, so it will not have any value yet.

Comment: @AbdullahFahim,please share your solution in an answer so that other people can also benefit out of your workaround.

Comment: Hi Vivek, for the interim period, I just made an interim page to setup the environment variables while I am planning to check the solution you offered. If I do something with that, I'll share my code here.